# How to include number of observation using sas

Tags: sas

I want to run a ols regression using SAS. I try to export the result into  dataset `out`. I want to have estimated coefficient, standard error, t statistics, and number of observations in my dataset. My code below does not include number of observations.

```
proc reg data = data noprint outest = out tableout;
        model y = a;
        by by_variable;
run;
```

I know one way to do it is using `ods output nobs=numobs;` However, when I run the regression by group, this process become unnecessarily time consuming.  I think 'ods output' just record the printed output. Printing the output out takes time, so the progress becomes much slower. THis is why I want to avoid it.  Is there any way to include number of observations using other method?

Comment: Can you post sample input and output data?  For input data you might be able to just reference one of the SASHELP tables.

Comment: Implicitly it's DF + 1 I think? You should confirm the exact relationship. DF would be in the same table as some of the other stats.

Comment: @Tom since the regression may exclude obs with missing values that may not be the best approach.

Comment: @Reeza Huh? An example with missing values would help.  You can even use SASHELP tables to demonstrate by adding a step to introduce missing values.

Comment: I can use 'proc reg data = data noprint outest = out edf;' to get the degree of freedom. But it does not provide standard error or t statistics.  Is there any way to get everything in one go.

Answer (score 1):

`ODS OUTPUT` does not 'just record the printed output'; it takes the feed that would be turned into the printed output and exports it in dataset format instead.  It's essentially the step *before* printed output.

As such, you can simply turn off the printed output if you don't want it, without harming `ods output`, using `ods exclude` (or other similar methods).

Here's one example.

```
ods exclude all;   *turn off all output;
ods output nobs=numobs;  *turn on just that output to that destination;
proc reg data = cars outest = out tableout;
        model cylinders=mpg_city;
        by origin;
run;
quit;
ods exclude none;  *turn output back on generally;
```

Comment: This did not speed up the process.

Comment: Then it's likely you are incorrect about the reason it is slow. For me, it's far faster than just running the code without the exclude - so it is fixing that part of the problem.

Comment: Compare ods everything, this is certainly faster. However, it takes more than 10 mins and I still have not got the output dataset. (I got thousands of regressions in total) If I just use 'proc reg data = cars outest = out tableout;', it only takes few seconds.

Comment: Perhaps determining the `nobs` dataset itself is complicated?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to get the values in one shot. You'll need to obtain two output tables and merge them. You've also stated you want number of observations, but is that the number in the dataset or the number used in the regression - because they can differ. I'll leave the merging of the final results to you since you haven't clarified the requirements.

The table you're interested in is the ParameterEstimates table which has everything, minus the number of observations. The ANOVA table does have the DF which is what I was thinking of, but that's not available in the ParameterEstimates table.

@Joe was correct as well, using ODS SELECT/EXCLUDE turns of all output to the window which should make your process faster. If you're experiencing a slowdown it's due to some other issue.

```
 *add some missing values;
data class;
set sashelp.class;
if age=12 then weight=.;
run;

ods select none;
proc reg data=class;
model weight=height;
ods output parameterEstimates=want_PE nobs=want_NOBS;
run;
ods select all;

proc print data=want_pe;
run;

proc print data=want_nobs;
run;
```